# sending SMS programmatically with iOS7 always adds a comma after the recipient

Tags: sms, ios7

I am sending SMS programmatically like this:

```
        MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.messageComposeDelegate = delegate;

        NSString *phoneNumber = @"123456789";
        picker.recipients =[NSArray arrayWithObject: phoneNumber];   
        picker.body =smsTxt;

        [delegate presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

While this works in 99,99% under iOS7 it adds a comma after the recipient in the SMS send-dialog

Like this:

To: **pete,**

So I can't send this SMS until I remove this comma

Any idea where this comes from - and how to get rid of this?

We reinstalled the iPhone already with the newest iOS7, reinstalled the app several times - but to no avail.

This happens only in 1 out of 1000 iOS7 users - really strange!
WIth previous iOS versions it never occured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
  picker.recipients =[NSArray arrayWithObjects: phoneNumber,nil];
```